# forward sled push: upright back vs leaning

Tags: exercise-technique, posture

So, I'm a bit confused by the correct way to perform sled push. In particular, whether it's best to keep your back upright, with arms bend in elbow, hands almost aligned with the body, or lean it as mush forward as you can with arms straight. Or both are valid for different goals?

Most people in the gym do the leaning, however sled push is not very popular so I'm not sure if what I see is actually representative of the majority.

My reason for considering more upright back is because in pankration (maybe other martial arts, but there I have no experience) leaning forward is really inviting an opponent to go for a lock, and when getting into grappling range it's not uncommon that you have to push forward using the legs. I suspect sled pushing with upright back can be a nice exercise for that purpose.

I've noticed that with leaning forward, weight I can effectively push for a fixed number of reps in a set is significantly larger.

I'm tempted to try the upright back approach, but I don't want to do something which is certainly less effective or straightaway harmful. Therefore I ask for advice.